# Access Applet running in a different browser window

Tags: java, javascript, applet, japplet

Is it possible to access and call methods from javascript, of an applet on a **different** browser window?

Else, is it possible to call javascript functions on a **different** browser window?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Different how? Did the one open the other?

Comment: The applet is constantly running on a different browser window. It may not be launched by the current window. Is it possible in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the browser windows are not related as parent-child (one window launched the other), then there is no way to communicate between them. (I don't think that even the HTML5 message passing stuff allows that, but I could be wrong.)